# How do I use modern coreutils on Mac?

Tags: macos, coreutils, csplit

How do I get modern coreutils on mac?

---

I ran into this problem using `csplit`:

`foo.txt`:

```
foo
1
foo
2
foo
3
```

```
$: csplit foo '^foo$' '{*}'
# error
```

Double checking the `manpage`, `man csplit`, `csplit` on Mac is the FreeBSD version and does not offer the `'{*}'` option.  In fact, I must provide the exact number of splits ahead of time.  This will either trigger a `czplit` re-implementation by me, or maybe I can get `GNU coreutils` on mac.

Is there a way?

Comment: I agree, this isn't optimal, but honestly, if this isn't performance-critical, you can just use your mac's default shell, `zsh` with its rather capable loops and regex operators to just do what you want.

Comment: GNU coreutils is easily installable from Homebrew. But because these utilities differ markedly from the BSD ones, the commands it adds to PATH have a `g` prefix (e.g., `gls`). You can add the directory containing the non-prefixed ones to `PATH` if you don't care about potentially breaking scripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU coreutils may be installed on macOS via, e.g., Homebrew.

Assuming that an initial installation of Homebrew has been made (see https://brew.sh), coreutils would be installed with

```bash
brew install coreutils
```

Homebrew will add a `g` prefix to the utilities that conflict with macOS base system utilities so that you get `gls`, `gcp`, `gcsplit`, etc.

To access the GNU coreutils *without* the `g` prefix, you may add the `$HOMEBREW_PREFIX/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin` directory to your `PATH`.